# Defer parts of scrape in scrapy

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, twisted, scrapy

I have the parse method given below, I uses selenium to first load a page, visits certain pages that cannot be accessed by a scraping directly from the spider, collects individual urls to another parse method which extracts items from the pages. The problem is, this parse method blocks other parsing untill all pages are visited. This chokes the system. I tried adding a sleep, but this stops the engine alltogether, and not just this `parse` method.

Any pointers as to how I could optimize this, or atleast make sleep work so that it doesnt stop the engine?

```py
def parse(self, response):
    '''Parse first page and extract page links'''

    item_link_xpath = "/html/body/form/div[@class='wrapper']//a[@title='View & Apply']"
    pagination_xpath = "//div[@class='pagination']/input"
    page_xpath = pagination_xpath + "[@value=%d]"

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get(response.url)
    log.msg('Loaded search results', level=log.DEBUG)

    page_no = 1
    while True:
        log.msg('Scraping page: %d'%page_no, level=log.DEBUG)
        for link in [item_link.get_attribute('href') for item_link in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(item_link_xpath)]:
            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_item_page)
        page_no += 1
        log.msg('Using xpath: %s'%(page_xpath%page_no), level=log.DEBUG)
        page_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(page_xpath%page_no)
        if not page_element or page_no > settings['PAGINATION_PAGES']:
            break
        page_element.click()
        if settings['PAGINATION_SLEEP_INTERVAL']:
            seconds = int(settings['PAGINATION_SLEEP_INTERVAL'])
            log.msg('Sleeping for %d'%seconds, level=log.DEBUG)
            time.sleep(seconds)
    log.msg('Scraped listing pages, closing browser.', level=log.DEBUG)
    browser.close()
    display.stop()
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information about your setup? I'm confused why `time.sleep` would be expected to help, unless you're using multiple threads, but you also tagged the question "twisted", suggesting that your system is async instead. The caller of `parse()` may also have some clues, if it's trying to aggregate all the results immediately instead of treating the output like a generator.

Comment: @thepaul Scrapy is built on twisted (and is thus async), which is why I tagged it with twisted.

Comment: Right, so, why would `time.sleep` be expected to help? It's a blocking call, and thus pretty incompatible with twisted, unless you have multiple threads and you only want to block a non-reactor thread.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish. Scrapy runs the reactor thread, and the individual scaping happens in different threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://gist.github.com/dangra/2781744) may help:

```
# delayspider.py
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.http import Request

DELAY = 5 # seconds


class MySpider(BaseSpider):

    name = 'wikipedia'
    max_concurrent_requests = 1

    start_urls = ['http://www.wikipedia.org']

    def parse(self, response):
        nextreq = Request('http://en.wikipedia.org')
        dfd = defer.Deferred()
        reactor.callLater(DELAY, dfd.callback, nextreq)
        return dfd
```

Output:

```
$ scrapy runspider delayspider.py 
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.15.1 started (bot: scrapybot)
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [wikipedia] INFO: Spider opened
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [wikipedia] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2012-05-24 11:01:54-0300 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2012-05-24 11:01:56-0300 [wikipedia] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.wikipedia.org> (referer: None)
2012-05-24 11:02:04-0300 [wikipedia] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page> from <GET http://en.wikipedia.org>
2012-05-24 11:02:06-0300 [wikipedia] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page> (referer: http://www.wikipedia.org)
2012-05-24 11:02:11-0300 [wikipedia] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2012-05-24 11:02:11-0300 [wikipedia] INFO: Dumping spider stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 745,
     'downloader/request_count': 3,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 29304,
     'downloader/response_count': 3,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 24, 14, 2, 11, 447498),
     'request_depth_max': 2,
     'scheduler/memory_enqueued': 3,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2012, 5, 24, 14, 1, 54, 408882)}
2012-05-24 11:02:11-0300 [wikipedia] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
2012-05-24 11:02:11-0300 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping global stats:
    {}
```

It uses Twisted's callLater to sleep.

Comment: Could you provide some additional explanation of how this helps the OP beyond linking the code?

Comment: I've added the gist inline.  If you do link to external pastebins, please always include the code so that if the external pastebin is unavailable, the stack overflow answer still makes sense.

Comment: the parse() method allows you to return a deferred?